# Bash: opening multiple files with diferent names in script from one directory

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, debian

I'm trying to make screen caps/previews of multiple video files (different names).
Im using script called SlickSlice, easy to use with one file.

I have tried

```
./slickslice-0.9 -x /dir/*
```

It didn't worked at all. Only first file was loaded and edited.

Script ussage with one file:

```
./slickslice-0.9 -x /dir/FILENAME
```

How to handle multiple files in the script and add them as parameter?
I saw few examples with "for" loop but it was only to rename files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work:

```
for foo in /dir/*; do
  ./slickslice-0.9 -x "$foo"
done
```